# Node HTTP proxy routetable else / not found

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I have a `node-http-proxy` server using the proxytable configuration:

```
var options = {
  router: {
    'a' : '127.0.0.1:81',
    'b': '127.0.0.1:82',
    'c': '127.0.0.1:83',
    'else' : '127.0.0.1:5000'
  }
};

httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);
```

Is there a way to run it so if the `hostname` is neither a, b, or c to use the `else` server?

Answer (score 0):

This may not have been possible at the time you asked the question, but the route table now supports regex:

```
var options = {
  router: {
    'a' : '127.0.0.1:81',
    'b': '127.0.0.1:82',
    'c': '127.0.0.1:83',
    '.*' : '127.0.0.1:5000'
  }
};
```